# GUI does not appear when running python code with VSCode and Pycharm

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, turtle-graphics

I was trying to write some python code, inside my code I imported the turtle module and when I ran my code on VSCode I expected to see a GUI window but instead I got the following errors:

[image]

And besides that I get a Problem Report for Python showing up:

[image]

This is what my code looks like:

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

my_turtle.shape("turtle")
my_turtle.color("red")
my_turtle.forward(100)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

My macOS version is 11.1 btw.

Comment: Does it work if you run it directly in a terminal?

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of text when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The Problem Report references Python 2.7.16, which is obsolete and no longer supported.

Comment: "macOS 11 or later required" appears on my terminal

Comment: If it references Python 2.7.16 then will updating Python to its latest version help?

Comment: Updating tp Python 3.x may help and in any event, you should be using more current version. Unfortunately that may not be easy on MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but apparently Python 2.7.16 does not support the Turtle module, so I switched my python version to 3.9.1 on the terminal and when I ran `python main.py` the GUI finally appeared.

I used the following command to switch python versions on my terminal:

```
alias python="python3"
```

Although I have solved this problem on my terminal, I have yet to see a way to change the python version on VSCode.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have that alias and use python3 directly yourself. Vscode knows how to reference the correct Python executable

Comment: I just solved this problem by following the steps in this blog post written by [Irfan](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should install python 3.9.1 directly into your machine, so you don't worry about it.